# Return statement continues to prompt user to input String

Tags: java, input, return, getter-setter

> The aim of my program is to take input of an attribute of an animal and then print the animal that has a corresponding attribute. I've used setter and getter methods along with three other methods that create the correct characteristics of the animals and then check if the attribute inputted corresponds with the animal.

> My issue is that my **input()** method that's supposed to return the inputted String will run once if you put in an attribute corresponding to the first animal, but if you input a attribute corresponding to the second or third animal it will re-prompt you two or three times respectively, and once the program does find the correct animal it will just continue to re-prompt the user until for input. Like this:

```
Enter one attribute you'd like in your pet: green
Enter one attribute you'd like in your pet: green
Enter one attribute you'd like in your pet: green
You can have a Parrot
Enter one attribute you'd like in your pet: green
Enter one attribute you'd like in your pet: green
You can have a Parrot
Enter one attribute you'd like in your pet: green
You can have a Parrot

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I'm not sure why this is happening or how to fix, all I need is the input prompt to happen once and then print the correct animal to the user. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks. My current code is this:

```
import java.util.*;

class Main {

    private static String name;
    private static String colour;
    private static String personality;
    private static String noise;

    public String input(){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter one attribute you'd like in your pet: ");
        String input = sc.next();
        return input;

    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name=name;
    }

    public void setColour(String colour) {
        this.colour = colour;
    }

    public void setPersonality(String personality) {
        this.personality = personality;
    }

    public void setNoise(String noise) {
        this.noise = noise;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }

    public String getColour(){
        return this.colour;
    }

    public String getPersonality(){
        return this.personality;
    }

    public String getNoise(){
        return this.noise;
    }

    public void PetOne(){
        Main petOne = new Main();
        String input = input();
        petOne.setName("pug");
        petOne.setColour("tan");
        petOne.setPersonality("playful");
        petOne.setNoise("woof");
        if(input.equals(petOne.getName()) || input.equals(petOne.getColour()) || input.equals(petOne.getPersonality()) || input.equals(petOne.getNoise())){
            System.out.println("You can have a Pug");

        } else PetTwo();
    }

    public void PetTwo() {
        Main petTwo = new Main();
        String input = input();
        petTwo.setName("cat");
        petTwo.setColour("brown");
        petTwo.setPersonality("affectionate ");
        petTwo.setNoise("meow");
        if(input.equals(petTwo.getName()) || input.equals(petTwo.getColour()) || input.equals(petTwo.getPersonality()) || input.equals(petTwo.getNoise())){
            System.out.println("You can have a Cat");

        } else PetThree();
    }

    public void PetThree() {
        Main petThree = new Main();
        String input = input();
        petThree.setName("parrot");
        petThree.setColour("green");
        petThree.setPersonality("intelligent");
        petThree.setNoise("squawk");
        if(input.equals(petThree.getName()) || input.equals(petThree.getColour()) || input.equals(petThree.getPersonality()) || input.equals(petThree.getNoise())){
            System.out.println("You can have a Parrot");

        } else  throw new RuntimeException
                ("Attempt to use real attributes n/0");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main m = new Main();
        m.PetOne();
        m.PetTwo();
        m.PetThree();
    }

}
```

Comment: `m.PetOne()` with input "green" calls `PetTwo()`, which in turn with the same input calls `PetTree()`. But then after all that runs, you have a call to `PetTwo()`, which with that input calls `PetThree()`. And then you have another call to `PetThree()`. Also you never close your instance of `Scanner`. Considering all that, I have to say the input you're getting is pretty normal.

Comment: Each of your pets calls the "next" pet, which asks for input.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the input() method from main() and saving the result as a String which you refer to in the Pet() methods.  Your input could be saved as a global variable or passed around as a parameter.  This will avoid asking for the same input many times over.

Also, run your program in debugging mode and go through it line by line to ensure you understand why it is currently asking the user for the input so often.  Debugging can be good for learning as well as fixing :)